# How to fluid images when resize window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to fluid images when resize window?.

I have HTML code like this :

```
<div class="box">
 <img src="http://demo.smooththemes.com/magazon/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/984632486_9d8ff89b63_b-642x336.jpg" />
</div>
```

And CSS :

```
.box {width:150px; height:60px; position:relative; overflow:hidden}
.box img{position:absolute; width:180px; height:80px; top:-10px; left:-10px}
```

When windows is resized, I want remove properties of (.box img): `top:-10px; left:-10px` and attribute more :  `min-width:100%, max-width:100%`. It means we have :

```
.box img{
position:absolute;
width:180px; height:80px; min-width:100%;  
top:(removed); left:(removed)}
```

How can I do it with Javascript or Jquery. Thanks for your help.

Comment: how when resize? any resize, any widht of the browsers window?

Comment: animate will make it move smoothly.  **$(_img_).animate({top:"", left:""});**  or something like that.  I would have to look at specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to agree with @Phorden that media queries are a good route for this.

However, if you *need* to do it with JS / jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.box img').css({'top': 'auto', 'left': 'auto', 'min-width': '100%'});
});
```

Comment: I'm using 'top':'auto' and 'left':'auto', specifically, because these are the initial (default) values provided by the browser.

Comment: Thanks. I did it with your help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about a jQuery or Javascript solution, but if you want a pure CSS solution, **CSS media Queries** is probably what you want. It is a foundational concept of responsive web design. More info on CSS Media Queries here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Thank. It is responsive design and I need more for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

add max-width:100% and height:auto to your images to make them resize proportional based on their parent:

```
.box img{
       position:absolute; 
       top:-10px; 
       left:-10px

       max-width: 100%; /* fits width of parent */
       height: auto;  /* resize height based on max-width, making it proportional *?
 }
```

.

Answer (score 1):

I think this script by Scott Jehl could be interesting for you although the images only change there dimensions at specific breakpoints.

[picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill)

It's very useful as you can define different picture sources for various resolutions.

The markup needed in combination with this script looks e.g. like this:

```
<span data-picture data-alt="Image description">
    <span data-src="small.jpg"></span>
    <span data-src="medium.jpg"     data-media="(min-width: 400px)"></span>
    <span data-src="large.jpg"      data-media="(min-width: 800px)"></span>
    <span data-src="extralarge.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)"></span>

    <!-- Fallback content for non-JS browsers. Same img src as the initial, unqualified source element. -->
    <noscript>
        <img src="external/imgs/small.jpg" alt="Image description">
    </noscript>
</span>
```